# Cannot boot into ubuntu after installing it on to hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I was prompted to reboot after finishing the installing of ubuntu kylin(i have same problem with regular ubuntu) I either boot right into windows or if I remove the usb, I boot from the usb again which is not helpful. I can see that I have them installed as 3 partitions (bios grub(1Mb), ext4, swap) but i can't find a way to boot it. I have done some searching and someone said the grub is installed right on the usb from a live usb install, but I can see the grub in my partitions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) after getting into your flavor of Linux
From terminal(Ctrl+T)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```